# Advanced cell reference in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to reference the cell "n" rows above the current cell, where n is an variable.  I tried the "cell" function, but it doesn't allow me to use string as argument as I must pass the reference without double quote in the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [OFFSET](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/offset.php) function or RANGE.